# IBM Z/os Rexx script returns 255 exit code

Tags: zos, rexx

I have simple Rexx script `hello_world.rexx`:

```
/* rexx */

SAY 'Hello World'

EXIT
```

Then I run it:

```
>./hello_world.rexx
Hello World
```

It executes well, but somehow I always get 255 exit code.

```
>echo $?
255
```

Does somebody know how to fix script to get `0` as exit code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are running the REXX code from USS.

See here =>  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxb600/bpx1rx32.htm

You can explicitly set return code 0 by using EXIT 0, for example:

/* rexx */

SAY 'Hello World'

EXIT 0

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxb600/bpx1rx32.htm) an return code of 255 indicates that the program was terminated. Use `exit 0` if you want a zero returned.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the RETURN keyword with a code:

```
RETURN 0
```